# Login with facebook in localhost

Tags: facebook

In my web app I'm try to add login with facebook field. I wanted to know is there is any way I could develop 'login with facebook' function in localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Just add a Platform in the settings of your App ("Website", for example) and enter "`http://localhost/`" in the input field named "Site URL". In the App Domains input field, enter "`localhost`".